# get value of checked checkbox list in array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have list of checkboxes that has all checkbox pre-checked when page load.

Firstly, I want to read all checkboxes (checked) value and store in global array.

Later, whenever any checkbox is clicked by user (un-checked / checked), I want to update the array with values of only checked checkboxes.

All this i want to do in jQuery.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to pull this into an array, you have an array of controls... it's effectively there already, no need to duplicate the effort.

Comment: Did you find a solution in any of the answers or comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
var arrCheckboxes;
var checkboxSelector = "input[type='checkbox']";
$("body").delegate(checkboxSelector , "click", function(){
    arrCheckboxes = $(checkboxSelector).map(function() {
        return this.checked;
    }).get();
});
```

(Maybe you should change the $("body") to a more precise container)

If you want an array with objects with name (...or id or maybe the element)... you can do something like this:

```
var arrCheckboxes;
var checkboxSelector = "input[type='checkbox']";
$("body").delegate(checkboxSelector , "change", function(){
    arrCheckboxes = $(checkboxSelector).map(function() {
        return { name: this.name, val: this.checked };
    }).get();
});
```

Comment: i have these checkboxes ul>li>input

Comment: $("ul").delegate(...  Add a class to the ul and your selector if you have multiple lists on your page. When you click the checkbox it will bubble up to the container (in this case <ul>). This way you can bind one event instead of one per checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="somevalue1" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" value="somevalue2" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" value="somevalue3" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" value="somevalue4" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" value="somevalue5" class="chk">
<script>
var someGlobalArray = new Array;

$(".chk").click(function() {
    someGlobalArray=[];
    $('.chk:checked').each(function() {
        someGlobalArray.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(someGlobalArray);
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is fine, how do i do updating when checkbox is checked again.

Comment: i have this function

function updateCategoryList() {
 //g_categoryList = [];
 $('.g_chkCat:checked').each(function() {
  g_categoryList.push($(this).val());
 });
 //$('#t').val(categoryList);
 alert("Length: "+g_categoryList.length +"  Values: "+g_categoryList);
}

how to i link click on check box to call this function again

Comment: $(".g_chkCat").click(function() {
    g_categoryList = [];
    $('.g_chkCat:checked').each(function() { g_categoryList.push($(this).val()); });
    //$('#t').val(categoryList);
    alert("Length: "+g_categoryList.length +" Values: "+g_categoryList);
}

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want is the *name* or *id* of the checked items, since checkbox *values* are boolean?

```
var checked = {};
$(':input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    var name= this.name;
    var val = this.checked;
    if (val) {
        checked[name] = val;
    }
}).on('change', function() {
    var name = this.name;
    var val = this.checked;
    if (val) {
        checked[name] = val;
    } else {
        delete checked[name];
    }
});
```

The object `checked` will then contain *keys*, and only those corresponding to *checked* items will appear in that object.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/tFYPF/