# i need to have a form get values from outside forms or a workaround

Tags: php, forms

i know little javascript and im guessing there is some way to do this but my problem persists in php and i would like to solve it in php

I have one main form which contains one `deleteAll` button and i have check boxes in the other multiple forms
how can i press my `deleteAll` button and get the names of the checkboxes checked (because they go with its id) and eventually grab their name and perform mysql to delete

here is my code that loops and produces one form for one delete all button
and loops through my database only to generate many forms like so

```
echo '<div class="span12"><form action="admin/tool/editvehicle.php" method="post">
<button id="deleteall" name="deleteall" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" >Delete</button></form>
</div>';
//get the total number of vehicles active in the database to loop through them and displaying them to manage
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('auto_id') FROM `auto`");
$all = mysql_result($query, 0);  //store the value so we can run this loop accordingly
$i = 1;
$auto_id = 0; //auto id equal to zero as starting point, it will increase randomly to as many vehicles it will diplay
while ($i <= $all)  //ie run for every car
{
    $fields = 'auto_id, year, make, model, engine, sound_system,mileage, price, att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8, 
    att9, att10, att11, att12, att13, att14, att15, picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, 
    picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12';
    //check where the auto id is greater then the previously one according to $auto_id which increments
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` > $auto_id"));
    $auto_id = $data['auto_id'];  //here is the magic, we set the auto id to the current one being spitted out so it follows through
    //now with all the $data retrieved from the database we can print car by car with its unique info and ids
    echo '<div id="displaycarwrap" class="span3 container">
    <input id="deletebox" type="checkbox" name="a">
    <a href"#"><img src="' . $data['picture1'] . '"></img></a>
    <form action="admin/tool/editvehicle.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <br><b>Price</b>: <input name="price" type="text" class="span2" value="' . $data['price'] . '">
            </li>
            <li>
                <button name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" >Delete Vehicle</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="editpictures" type="submit" >Edit Pictures</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" name="editauto" class="btn  btn-inverse" >Apply Changes</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-mini  show_hide icon-th-list" href="#" rel="#slidingDiv'. $i .'">View details</button>
        <div id="slidingDiv'. $i .'" class="toggleDiv" style="display: none;">
        <ul> <br />
            <li><b>Year</b>:<br /><input type="text" name="year" value="' . $data['year'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Make</b>: <br /><input type="text" name="make" value="' . $data['make'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Model</b>: <br /><input type="text" name="model" value="' . $data['model'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Mileage</b>: <br /><input type="text" name="mileage" value="' . $data['mileage'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Engine</b>:<br /> <input type="text" name="engine" value="' . $data['engine'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Stereo</b> <br /><input type="text" name="sound_system" value="' . $data['sound_system'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 1 </b> <input type="text" name="att1" value="' . $data['att1'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 2</b> <input type="text" name="att2" value="' . $data['att2'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 3</b> <input type="text" name="att3" value="' . $data['att3'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 4</b> <input type="text" name="att4" value="' . $data['att4'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 5</b> <input type="text" name="att5" "value="' . $data['att5'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 6</b> <input type="text" name="att6" value="' . $data['att6'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 7</b> <input type="text" name="att7" value="' . $data['att7'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 8</b> <input type="text" name="att8" value="' . $data['att8'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 9</b> <input type="text" name="att9" value="' . $data['att9'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 10</b> <input type="text" name="att10" value="' . $data['att10'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 11</b> <input type="text" name="att11" value="' . $data['att11'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 12</b> <input type="text" name="att12" value="' . $data['att12'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 13</b> <input type="text" name="att13" value="' . $data['att13'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 14</b> <input type="text" name="att14" value="' . $data['att14'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><b>Attribute 15</b> <input type="text" name="att15" value="' . $data['att15'] . '" class="span2"></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="auto_id" value="' . $data['auto_id'] . '" class="span2" readonly><li>
        <ul>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>';
    $i++; //used for the while loop
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: so basically you want javascript code to select all checkbox in a single form right?

Comment: @saranbanerjee well i did wanted to keep it in the php family but if i have to use javascript i will because im seeing that i have no solution for this in php, so a quick jquery function that does what? please help me briefly outline this function so i can switch to notepad and code with no doubt

Comment: look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533081/get-value-of-checked-checkbox-list-in-array-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can add form id to form inside while loop and can call jquery to get checked checkboxes values like

```
    $("input[name='foo[]']:checked:enabled",'#myform');
```

where myform is your form id 
 OR 
  for all checked check boxes try jquery :

```
   $("input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

Comment: ok so do you think jquery will pick up all the checked boxes even if they are in seperate forms, jquery wouldnt care? it will just get all the checkboxes that are checked on that page? im going to try this BRB